undefined reference to "WinMain"
I am new to c++ and trying to use SDL2 on my Mingw Compiler(Msys2)
After I compiled with #include "SDl2\SDL2.h" my compiler kept giving me this message:
C:/M/B/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexewin.c:67:(.text.startup+0xc5): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Environment:
Editor: Cp editor
Compile command: g++ -Wall -O2 -std=c++17
I tried using the -municode to reference to wWinMain but that didnt work(may be wWinMain doest exist)
Weirdly enough #include <bits/stdc++.h> works fine(I dont know if stdc++.h uses WinMain)
Also tried reininstalling SDL2 through Msys2 pacman

That's the linker that is complaining. Did you try linking with the SDL library/libraries? Also: Never #include <bits/stdc++.h>

Show your code and compiler flags. Also see How do I use SDL2 in my programs correctly?.

You need to show us the code you have. Your code might be fine, but until we see it we have no way of knowing.

g++ -Wall -O2 -std=c++17 is not the full build command. Can you show the rest that includes your source files and linking to the SDL libraries?

Also tried reininstalling SDL2 through Msys2 pacman This is most likely not an installation issue. It's likely either you didn't properly link to the SDL libraries, you didn't build all of your source files, could be a problem in how you are handling SDL main, or your code doesn't have the required int main() or WinMain. However with that said you gave us almost no information to help solve the linker problem so its currently impossible to provide an answer without guessing.
